# Bash script to modify /etc/hosts file

Tags: linux, bash

When I´m running the next bash it work´s in the first time, but if I try to run again it dosent modify the file

```
oldHS=$HOSTNAME
echo -n "New hostname: "
read NHOST
sed -i "s/$oldHS/$NHOST/g" /etc/hosts
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname $NHOST
read -p "In the following file please validate the change. If it is correct, press control + x otherwise make the change and press control + o. Press enter to continue"
sudo nano /etc/hosts
hostnamectl
read -p "Presione enter para finalizar"
```

The hostnamectl set-hostname $NHOST always make the change but the script only the first time make the change in the /etc/hosts file

Comment: Does `$HOSTNAME` change to reflect the new name? It might require starting a new login shell.

Comment: You are correct, it doesn´t reflect the change. I made this chanage an it works. Thank you!

oldHS=$(hostname)

Answer (score 0):

As Shawn said in the comments, the $HOSTNAME doesn`t reflect the chanague until I start a new shell. I made a change in the oldHS variable for this and it works

```
oldHS=$(hostname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "new_hostname" > /etc/hostname && hostnamectl set-hostname "new_hostname"
```

Replace both occurrences of "new_hostname" with the desired hostname you want to set. When using this as EC2 userdata, the script will update the /etc/hostname file and set the new hostname using hostnamectl.

Comment: `hostnamectl` is enough  to replace / edit/ rename ...